# Elasticsearch path.logs is not working correctly

Tags: elasticsearch

When I set the path.logs in the elasticsearch.yml I get the behaviour, that some logs are in the defined folder, but some stuff is also always created in the elasticsearch root folder.
So in the elasticsearch root folder in logs I find the pid file gc stderr and stdout file...
When I remove the folder it´s always created on startup.
How can I prevent ES from splitting up in two folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `path.logs` in `elasticsearch.yml` change the path for the elasticsearch logs only.

Logs related to the `jvm` like the gc logs are set in the `jvm.options` file and the PID file location is set when starting up elasticsearch using the option `-p`.

If you installed elasticearch using a package manager like `yum` or `apt`, you will need to edit the systemd `elasticsearch.service` and change the `PID_DIR` variable.

If you are starting elasticsearch using the command line you will need to pass the PID file location using the option `-p`, something like `-p /path/to/elasticsearch.pid`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I guess your answer is correct, but I´m on Windows.

Comment: If you are running as a service on windows, you have the `SERVICE_LOG_DIR` variable, maybe this can solve your problem. [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html#windows-service-settings)